# Django upload image from form

Tags: html, django

I got this weird problem. I work with a PostgreSQL database.
I made a model and form and migrated it, registered it in admin.py.

When I am in the admin panel, I can add data to the form. One of the fields is an image, that is copied to media/images in the process. (MEDIA is declared in settings.py).
This works like a charm. All the data (including the image) is saved in the database and can be displayed in html.

But working from the admin-panel was not my first choice, so I made a html page with a form to input the data to the database. I fill in the fields, add the image and submit it.
It tells me that the data is successfully added to the database.

When I look in the admin panel, the record is indeed added, all the info is filled in, BUT the image is not. (it says no file is chosen). Also the image  itself is not stored in media/images.
If I add the image again in the admin panel, and save it, it works. So something goes wrong from the form to the database with saving the image.

I googled a lot, and read that I should add enctype="multipart/form-data"  in my form method="POST".
I looked at all the files and compared what is different in my code. But I can not find it.

The code: (In some files I only show relevant code, not whole)..

index.html

```
 <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {% csrf_token %}
             
                {{ form.as_p }}

                <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-secondary">
            </form>
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('monsters', views.monsters, name='monsters'),
    path('monsterinfo', views.monsterinfo, name='monsterinfo'),
    path('addmonster', views.addmonster, name='addmonster'),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from .models import Underdark_Monsters
from django.contrib import messages
from .forms import UnderdarkForm
    
def addmonster(request):
        submitted = False
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = UnderdarkForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                img_obj = form.instance
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/addmonster?submitted=True', {'form': form, 'img_obj': img_obj})
        else:
            form = UnderdarkForm
            if 'submitted' in request.GET:
                submitted = True
        return render(request, 'addmonster.html', {'form': form, 'submitted': submitted})
    
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms.fields import NullBooleanField
# Create your models here.

class Underdark_Monsters(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True,
        upload_to='images/')

    table = models.ImageField(blank=True,
        upload_to='images/')
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Underdark_Monsters


# Maak een addmonster formulier



class UnderdarkForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Underdark_Monsters
        fields = ('image', 'cr', 'name', 'source',
                  'type', 'size', 'Alignment', 'tags', 'info', 'table')
        labels = {
            'image': 'Image:',
            'cr': '',
            'name': '',
            'source': '',
            'type': '',
            'size': '',
            'Alignment': '',
            'tags': '',
            'info': '',
            'table': 'Table:',
                    }
        widgets = {
            'cr': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Cr'}),
            'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Name'}),
            'source': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Source'}),
            'type': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Type'}),
            'size': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Size'}),
            'Alignment': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Alignment'}),
            'tags': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Tags'}),
            'info': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Info'}),
            }
```

Hopefully someone can explain to me why adding an image in the admin panel works, and directly from a html form all data is stored except the image. (and also the file is not stored in media/images).  I am sure it must be something small, or a typo, since basically it works if I take the admin panel route...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to pass `request.FILES` to your form.

```
form = UnderdarkForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
```

Comment: Sir, you are a lifesaver. 1,5 day searching gave me nothing, 5 minutes here, and request.files added, IT works!

Comment: Glad to hear that :)